# UWP Phone - Cellular Tower Changed

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp

I would like to know whether it is at all possible to be notified within Windows Phone (UWP) that the phone switched between cellular towers.

Many thanks in advance!
Kind regards,

Comment: I wouldn't expect phones to be able to establish which *tower* they are connected to, as far as the device is concerned, if there's a signal, then **who cares**? That being said, **why** on earth would you *need* to know when the cellular tower changes?

Comment: @MikeEason: Diagnostics, for example. Maybe an application wishes to correlate its position and the frequency of base station switches. Or simply for display to the user. There are likely other legitimate reasons to request this information.

Comment: @MikeEason: Thanks for your reply. There is a very good reason why I want to know this. Reason being, I need to know when cell tower has changed, because there is a discount value that is offered, based on the cell tower the subscriber is connected to. Discount is related to data charges and bundles that the end user can purchase. _So I guess, that's why I care and why on earth I need to know_